# Seeking Clarification Regarding Classifiers Accuracy

Tags: machine-learning

I am using the classification learner in MATLAB. On training the model, some classifiers return higher accuracy, whereas, the other returns low. As i am new to machine learning, i would like to inquire as to how should we proceed from this point, i.e., do we need to only take the classifiers with the highest accuracy into consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two techniques of choosing the best model:

In the first one you split your dataset into 3 subsets: *train*, *validation*, and *test*. In this case you choose a type of model to use (e.g. LogicalRegression, RandomForestClassifier, etc.) and its hyperparameters. After training you test your model on validation dataset. Than you repeat that with other hyperparameters and models. In the end you should choose best model based on validation accuracy.

The other similar technique is cross-validation. Here, you split your dataset into 2: *train* and *test*. And later you train and validate your model with cross-valition (e.g. K-Fold, Repeated Stratified K-Fold, etc.). And in the end you choose model with the best permormance.